# How to create multiple clickable items carousel with bootstrap 3 exactly on this sample

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to create something like this slider: http://weeklynews-html.mipdesign.com

I have checked other examples on jsddle and the other demos on stackoverflow.com but none them are quite exactly like this one.

I have made one to try but there is some resolution, responsive and styling issues: http://www.bootply.com/7rlMN3nFQm

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't specific enough but taking a quick look it seems there's inconsistencies with your wrapper classes and image widths and image wrapper divs. Change those to be consistent and you'll be in better shape.